# Leaving threatened range with Opportunistic Withdrawal

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

The Opportunistic Withdrawal feat from D&D 4e PHB3 says:

> While you are adjacent to an enemy granting combat advantage to you your movement doesn't provoke opportunity Attacks from that enemy.

If an enemy grants me advantage, does Opportunistic Withdrawal allow me to move out of the threatened area without suffering OA? An OA is an immediate interruption so technically I'm still adjacent, so how does it work in this case?

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for clarifying. :) Reopened. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

An opportunity attack provoked by moving out of a threatened square takes place immediately before the movement (the trigger).  Opportunistic Withdrawal helps you to avoid provoking any OAs from the adjacent enemy granting CA caused by any movement on your part.  Note that if the creature had reach and you tried to move from 10' away to 15' away (after moving from 5' to 10' with no OAs) you would provoke an OA since you are not adjacent when the trigger occurs.

> #### Opportunity Attack *(4e Compendium)*
>
> **Interrupts Target’s Action**: An opportunity action takes place ***before*** the target finishes its action.

In this case, the triggering action should be considered the part of your movement going from 5' away to another square 5' away (circling the enemy) or 10' away (disengaging from the enemy).  Continuing to move away from the enemy (10' away to 15' away) would be considered a separate triggering action.